# How often are the top users in a tag calculated?

Tags: support, tags, tag-score

I've just been going through and unifying [itcl](/questions/tagged/itcl) with [incr-tcl](/questions/tagged/incr-tcl) because though the first existed before and the second didn't, the second is much closer to the formal name of the thing to which it refers to. So far, so ho hum.

But now that I've adjusted all the questions so that they're tagged with the improved tag, I can't nominate any synonyms for it. OK, I'm not sure if I have 5 upvotes in the tag (I *might* do) but when I look at the list of top users in it, it's empty! “A-hah! Needs a recalc!” I think.

So, how often are such recalculations performed? How long do I have to wait before I can see whether it is reasonable for me to try to propose a tag synonym?

Comment: Tag scores are updated at approximately 03:00 UTC, so wait at least another 13 hours or so.

Comment: Every 6-8 weeks ;-)

Comment: Happened to me as well. I retagged the question of one of my most-upvoted answers with a proposed synonym (it was a clear need for that tag anyway, so this isn't gaming) so that I _could_ propose the synonym. Had to wait a while.

Comment: Weird; that question didn't come up when I searched…